# How do I insert a procedure result into a table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am using a procedure to loop through a table and perform a different procedure on each row (this procedure uses other tables and works fine, returns correct result set). Here is my attempt:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE user_loop()
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users INTO n;
SET i=0;
WHILE i<n DO 
SET @cur_id = (SELECT user_id from users LIMIT i,1);
INSERT INTO results CALL other_proc(@cur_id);
SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
End;
$$
```

Not sure what the correct syntax is in order to do this, I looked but couldn't find any examples.

Comment: It can't be done in MySql. When a procedure is called from another procedure, the calling procedure cannot read a resultset returned from called procedure.

Comment: What should I do then? Nest it all in one giant procedure?

Comment: Yes, you can create one big procedure. Alternatively save a resultset in a temporary table in the called procedure, then retrieve rows from that table in the calling procedure.

Comment: Feel free to put it as an answer so that I can accept it.